# Return data in pipe del format

Tags: sql-server

I have the below example and trying to run a script in SQL to return data in required format. Just need some help with the "Header", "Data" and "Trailer" part.

```
H|Peter|Blum|2012/07/30|1
D|11399011005434578|Jason|Smith|8002235091083|0126531988|199 Lever Road Centurion Gauteng 0067|23.45|Your next payment is due on 2012/09/02|2012/07/29|Active
D|11399022005434578|Mike|Smith|8004235091083|0126531988|299 Lever Road Centurion Gauteng 0067|55.00|Your next payment is due on 2012/09/03|2012/06/29|Active
D|11399033005434578|Peter|Smith|8052235091083|0126531988|399 Lever Road Centurion Gauteng 0067|77.99|Your next payment is due on 2012/09/04|2012/05/29|Active
T|3
```

Comment: And?   Are you getting an error?   What is your question?

Comment: What format is that? Databases return data sets, not formatted text. Is this the result of a query? Are you asking how to return a single line of text instead of rows? What language are you using and why don't you simply use your language's query mechanism to return the data and format it in any way you want?

Comment: What is the data? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, this is the result of a query. Question is - How do I add a "Header" and "Trailer" record using a simple select statement..

Answer (score 0):

From the example you have provided I gather that you are trying to create a file.
You need to use a [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms162802.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) utility to create files.

The way you would approach it is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ##FileData( ID INT IDENTITY, RowString VARCHAR( MAX ))
INSERT INTO ##FileData
SELECT 'H|Peter|Blum|2012/07/30|1'

INSERT INTO ##FileData
SELECT 'D|' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, Col1 ) + '|' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, Col2 ) + '|' + ....
FROM MyTable

/* Get record count */
DECLARE @RowCount = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #FileData ) - 1

INSERT INTO ##FileData
SELECT 'T|' + CONVERT( VARCHAR, @RowCount )

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell
N'bcp "SELECT RowString FROM ##FileData" queryout  C:\MyFile.txt  -c -r\r\n -S[ServerName] -U[username] -P[password] '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Header and Trailer with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT {Query that generates Header}, 0 AS ord
UNION ALL 
SELECT {Query that generates Data Rows}, 1 AS ord
UNION ALL
SELECT {Query that generates Trailer}, 2 AS ord
ORDER BY ord ASC
```